# DTS dependent SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for an easy way to tell which of the 500 databases on my server are being hit by the 99 active DTS packages. I am running SQL Server 2008 R2. The DTS packages are not stored in the database. They are stored in the file system.

Comment: Are the connection managers fixed or set at run time?  If fixed, you can just parse the .dtsx files (It's just XML).  If set at run time, look into that process to see which dbs are set for which jobs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with .Net then its fairly easy to write a c# app to iterate through your packages and document the different Connections.
EG:

```
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;


app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application(); 
pkg = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\temp\mypackage.dtsx", null);
foreach (ConnectionManager cm in pkg.Connections)
{
foreach (DtsProperty prop in cm.Properties)
            {
                if (prop.Set)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        string s = prop.GetValue(o).ToString();

                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
}
```